# Internet Explorer 7 CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, alignment, stylesheet

So I have built a website and I looked at it on internet explorer 7 and the menu bar is seriously misaligned.  I looked into conditional comments and tried it out, and I don't know if I'm missing something. I put the conditional comment in the head tag of the website and then created a css style sheet just for ie7 and it didn't seem to do anything.  Can someone tell me if there is a quick fix to this situation or a step by step to the conditional comment and custom stylesheet method?  Any kind of help would be appreciated.  Thanks.  The website is here http://sgconstruction.org.  The CSS involves a float of the page links to the left and a float right on the facebook and yelp icons within the blue bar.  Both positions are relative.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue involves the CSS you are using for your `#connectguy` `<div>`. This element is a block-level element which you have set to `display: inline-block`. Unfortunately, Internet Explorer 7 only recognizes `inline-block` on elements which are inline by default. You can work around this by setting the `<div>` to `display: inline` in your IE7 stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

check applying * before the css property you likes to apply for ie7 and below browsers only.
for eg:

```
#test {*color: #999;   /*hack for IE7 and below*/

        color: #F00;/*for all other browsers*/}
```